# c: check if a function is defined in main.c from external file

Tags: c

I have a .c file (external.c) that is going to be used in several different projects:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printHello() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    // Check if donePrinting is defined in main.c here and call it if it is
    donePrinting(); 
}
```

These different projects all have a main.c that call printHello(), but not all of them have donePrinting in them.  For example some look like this:

```
#include "external.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int donePrinting() {
    printf("Done printing Hello World\n");
}

int main()
{
   printHello();
   return 0;
}
```

while others look like this:

```
#include "external.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printHello();
   return 0;
}
```

Is there a way I can check if donePrinting() exists when inside external.c?  If not what would be a work around for this?  I was thinking of defining a global variable in main.c that said if donePrinting exists or not and checking that global variable in printHello().

Comment: Yes, if you try to compile this without the `donePrinting` function, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: Run-time checking will not work, as you will get an error when you *build* about missing function. And no there is really no way to check if an external symbol exists or not, because C uses the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), where each *unit* is compiled separately from every other *unit*. The compiler only knows what's in the *current* unit, the one it's currently compiling. There are ways to work around the issue, as mentioned in the answer by Lantig.

Answer (score 3):

A mild form of dependency injection is what you need. Pass a pointer to the function that needs executing into `printHello`:

```
void printHello(void (*postPrintCB)(void)) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    // Check if donePrinting is defined in main.c here and call it if it is
    if (postPrintCB)
      postPrintCB(); 
}
```

That way, projects with a `donePrinting` function can call it like this:

```
printHello(donePrinting);
```

And projects without a `donePrinting` function can call it without:

```
printHello((void(*)(void))0);
```

You can of course typedef this thing a bit to make it easier on the eyes:

```
typedef void postPrintCB(void);
#define NULL_POST_PRINT_CB ((postPrintCB*)0)

void printHello(postPrintCB* callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)

A weak symbol allows you to provide a default implementation (that possibly does nothing), that can be overwritten by your `main.c` if you feel the need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it at linking

Require all projects to define `donePrinting()`. Just add a function that does nothing to the projects that lack it. Or provide a central definition in a separate file and the projects that need an empty definition can add that file to their build step.